# How can I mass rename many audio files?

Tags: audio, batch-rename

I need to rename many audio files, so that their file names show artist and song name. File formats are mp3 and flac. Is there a way to do it quickly? Or maybe there is a program for this?

Comment: where will you get Artist and song name ? Are they part of metadata of the files that you have ?

Comment: I use Ubuntu (but it has Wine, so windows programs are not a problem). Artist and song name are located in IdTags in files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've used [MP3Tag](http://www.mp3tag.de/en/) for this in the past. You can batch rename via `sprintf()`-ish format strings that pull various bits from ID3 tags.

Answer (score 0):

Some recommended tag editors:
en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tag_editor

I just used the Java-based **Entagged**, which is really simple and smart, so I can recommend it:
[Entagged](http://entagged.sourceforge.net/about.php)